# Index on which tablespace

Tags: database, oracle, jdbc, indexing, tablespace

How to find out which 'tablespace' a particular 'index' belongs to. (oracle)
(need to use it via jdbc)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The information is in the [ALL_INDEXES](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1096.htm#sthref1147) (or USER_INDEXES) view:

```
select tablespace_name
from all_indexes
where owner = 'MYSCHEMA'
and index_name = 'MYINDEX';
```

Comment: Potentially a partitioned index may cover several tablespaces. ALL_SEGMENTS is an alternative view

Answer (score 1):

`user_indexes.tablespace_name` is null for partitioned indices.

[Viewing Information About Partitioned Tables and Indexes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16541/part_admin005.htm) suggests that `user_ind_partitions` view can be used to check containing tablespace for each separate index partition:

```
select index_name, partition_name, tablespace_name from user_ind_partitions
    where index_name = 'MYINDEX';
```